# Multigroup SEM analysis - parameters test

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm working with SEM in social-mobility framework as I want to use different survey-questions to define the cognitive ability as a latent factor and in turn use it as an exogenous regression path.
The model is defined as follows:

```
sem<- ' 
#Measurement model - latent variables  
ability =~ c_cgwri_dv + c_cgwrd_dv + c_cgs7ca_dv + c_cgvfc_dv + c_cgna_dv
education=~edu_r 
r_class=~respondent_class 
origin_class=~max_class 
agree =~ c_big5a_dv 
consc =~ c_big5c_dv
neur =~ c_big5n_dv 
open =~ c_big5o_dv 
extro =~ c_big5e_dv 

#Structural model - Pahts 
ability ~ a*o_class 
education ~ b*ability + c*origin_class + d*agree + e*consc + f*neur + g*open + h*extro 
r_class ~ i*education + l*ability + m*origin_class + n*agree + o*consc + p*neur + q*open + r*extro 

#Indirect effects: 
i_ability := b*i 
i_originclass := (a*l) + (c*i) + (a*b*i)
i_agree := d*i 
i_consc := e*i 
i_neur := f*i 
i_open := g*i 
i_extro := h*i 

#Correlations
c_cgwri_dv ~~ c_cgwrd_dv
c_cgs7ca_dv ~~ c_cgna_dv
c_cgwri_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
c_cgwrd_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
c_cgvfc_dv ~~ c_cgna_dv
c_cgs7ca_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
agree ~~ ability 
consc ~~ ability 
neur ~~ ability 
open ~~ ability 
extro ~~ ability
o_class ~~ agree + consc + neur + open + extro
'
```

I want to perform a multi-group analysis by gender and therefore I was comparing the free and constrained model to check for differences. The ANOVA reveals significant differences, but now I have some troubles. Indeed, constraining and relaxing the possible paths would be exhausting and inefficient, nor desirable.

If I fix the regression paths based on theory and assumptions and let free some important variables (education, origin and ability), then how can I check whether the unstandardized coefficient between males and females are significantly different?

Thanks for your help and support!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Indeed, constraining and relaxing the possible paths would be exhausting and inefficient, nor desirable." If you want to look for differences, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, but I may have different and different types of combinations of paths that I need to constrain and relax in this model, which would be extremely time-consuming. In this framework, makes theoretical sense to set free education, social origin and ability while keep fix all the others. But (how) can I compare the free unstandardized coefficient between gender? Or what would be the best way? Thanks